# Working with a JSON on a third-part server

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

I'm developing an Android application with cordova, I need to read the json file from this address: [Dati.venezia.it](http://dati.venezia.it/sites/default/files/dataset/opendata/livello.json) and put it into a json variable. i have tried using jQuery getJson but i had problems with CORS i have also tried the same think with JSONP but i havent got how it works.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
console.log("start");
var url = 'http://dati.venezia.it/sites/default/files/dataset/opendata/livello.json?callback=?';
this.risultato= $.getJSON(url, function(data){

}); 
console.log("end");
```

and this was the attempt with getJson

```
$.getJSON('http://dati.venezia.it/sites/default/files/dataset/opendata/livello.json', function (data) {
  console.log(data);

  var items = data.items.map(function (item) {
    return item.key + ': ' + item.value;
  });

  showData.empty();

  if (items.length) {
    var content = '<li>' + items.join('</li><li>') + '</li>';
    var list = $('<ul />').html(content);
    showData.append(list);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that you can use `jsonp` as a workaround.  Looking at Dati.venezia.it , it doesn't look like it currently supports `jsonp`.  You'll need to have the endpoint *Dati.venezia.it* provide a callback for `jsonp` to work.

Additionally, the endpoint is missing the response header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, which won't allow other sites to pull data from it without that header.  This is why you're running into CORS issues.  If you have control of that website, you'll need to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to it's response headers.

Comment: thank you so if i have understood correctly i can't take that data without have directly access to Dati.venezia.it Server

Comment: Unfortunately, yes...  You can't get it via `getJSON`.  There are other methods to scrape data off the internet, if that is what you're looking to do?

Comment: In that json there are the data of the sea level in venice that data is updated every 10 minutes, i have to fetch data every 10 minutes. what else can I do?

Comment: It might be helpful for you to know that CORS is only a browser security issue.  I'd recommend some light reading on it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Therefore, to bypass CORS issue is to not run the code in the browser.  You can stand up a Node.js server to fetch that data and handle it any way you need to, and then pass it to your web page.